How to export react mui charts as PDF from the server side
Im using mui to draw charts in my frontend, specifically a barchart and a piechart and i would like to know how can i export them from the backend as pdfs, im currently using pdfmake but i cant really print out charts with it, so my question would be is there another library that i can use to export charts similar to the mui ones, or should i redo the charting in the frontend with another library
I tried adding a div to the charts so i'd get its id and try to work around it to make it a base64 image string and pass it to the pdfmake service function in my backend but that wouldnt work.
so lets say i want to export this for example :
      <PieChart
              series={[
                { 
                  data: [{ value: ticketpie.treated, label: t('dashboard.tickets.treated') },
                         { value: ticketpie.nontreated, label:t('dashboard.tickets.nonTreated')}
                        ],
                  innerRadius: 60,
                  highlightScope: { faded: 'global', highlighted: 'item' },
                  faded: {  additionalRadius: -30, color: 'gray' },
                },
              ]}
              sx={{
                [`& .${pieArcLabelClasses.root}`]: {
                  fill: 'white',
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                },
              }}
              height={250}
            />

what should i do ?
